# Pandas - pd.read_html, Problems reading negative values

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to convert this table into a pandas DataFrame. My problem here is that pandas do not recognize the negative values in the table.

```
import pandas as pd

url = 'http://www.scb.se/en_/Finding-statistics/Statistics-by-subject-area/Prices-and-Consumption/Consumer-Price-Index/Consumer-Price-Index-CPI/Aktuell-Pong/33779/Consumer-Price-Index-CPI/287612/'

df = pd.read_html(url,index_col='Year',header=0,parse_dates=True)[0]
print(df)
```

Any suggestions how i can proceed?

Thank you in advance

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "recognize the negative values"?. When I ran your code I got both positive and negative values in the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That table is using a different [hyphen character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2011/index.htm) rather than the ASCII minus.  You could do something like this to replace and re-convert to floats.

```
In [64]: df.iloc[0,0]
Out[64]: u'\u20111.1'

In [65]: for column in df:
    ...:     if df[column].dtype == np.object_:
    ...:         df[column] = df[column].str.replace(u'\u2011', '-').astype(float)

In [66]: df.iloc[0,0]
Out[66]: -1.1000000000000001
```

Comment: Thank you Chrisb. Works great now!